# Video tagging technology

Tags: java, video

I need some suggestion over a strange thing I want to do. I am currently working on a project where I want to analyze a video file. A human user will play a video file and will pause the video at some points. In the paused video, the user wants to tag someone.

Please suggest me if any API is available to do so?

It would be great if API is Java related.

Thanks,

Comment: It sounds like youtube tagging, eh?

Comment: Yeah, it is like youtube tagging..